Accidentally Partially Removed RAID 1 Mount Point. Is My RAID Okay?
I accidentally ran sudo rm -r on my RAID 1 mount point. I immediately realized my error, panicked, and hit CTRL+C to cancel. Some damage was already done. The lost+found directory and some of my data is gone, but most of it is still there. I can recover my lost data but I am worried about the integrity of the RAID and about the lost+found directory. So I have two questions:

Is my RAID okay?
Suppose I deleted the whole RAID mount point. This should only delete the data and the mount point, but the RAID itself would still be intact. So it could be remounted and I could restore the data from a backup. Is that correct?

Do I need to worry about the lost+found directory?
If I understand correctly, the lost+found directory only contains names for unlniked files that were found on the disk. So deleting it should not be a problem, as the unliked files themselves are not deleted and they will be found again and placed with a new name in lost+found. Is that correct?


Here is some info output of the RAID:
user@host:~ $ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      5860385344 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/44 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

user@host:~ $ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri May 31 11:25:15 2024
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 5860385344 (5.46 TiB 6.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 5860385344 (5.46 TiB 6.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Fri Sep 27 15:14:40 2024
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : host:0  (local to host host)
              UUID : ...
            Events : 87057

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1

user@host:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0  5.5T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0  5.5T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0  5.5T  0 raid1 /mount/raid1
sdb           8:16   0  5.5T  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0  5.5T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0  5.5T  0 raid1 /mount/raid1
...


In summary everything looks fine to me as a layman, but I am asking here to make sure.
Any help or reference points would be much appreciated!

Note: AFAIK mklost+found is still the best way to re-create lost+found. I mean: creating it manually with mkdir may be suboptimal.

It's fine to delete files with rm on an mdadm raid. Happens all day every day, perhaps not quite so accidentally. If missing lost+found is an issue, e2fsck or mklost+found will recreate it.
If you deleted your mdadm.conf, you'd have to make a new one.
If you are growing your raid using --backup-file and you deleted that backup file, that could be a problem. But this file has to be stored outside the raid, anyway.
Some extreme corner cases aside, if no issues appeared so far, it should be fine, as far as mdadm raid is concerned.

Thanks I am more relaxed now. But out of curiosity, if I accentially ran rm -r on the RAID mount point, would it break the RAID?

No, "rm -r" works at a different level than the RAID, so it should be impossible for any ext4 operations to "break" the RAID. You might delete all your data, and render the system unbootable (depending on what was deleted) but the RAID will be fine (if totally inaccessible).  :-)
